# Finding periodicity in last non zero digits of factorials.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a_n$ be the last non zero digit in the representation of $n!$, does the sequence of $a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$, ...,$a_n$ become periodic after a finite number of terms?

I am a high school student and found this question in a number theory book in a library, I have been trying to do this question for a while but I haven't succeeded.

I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. See [A008904](https://oeis.org/A008904):

> This sequence is not ultimately periodic. This can be deduced from the fact that the sequence can be obtained as a fixed point of a morphism.

Comment: That went from up my head, but I got a feel of proof and found the answer